# increment by 2 instead of 1 after button is clicked

Tags: c#, winforms

This is my code

```
int Moneycount;
        private void mButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Moneycount++;
            MoneyCount.Text = Moneycount.ToString();
        }
        private void level1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }
```

"mButton" is incremented by 1 every time I press it,

so I want it to be incremented by 2 instead of 1 after I press "level1"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `level1` being an actual `Button`, it might be useful to make it a `Checkbox` instead, and then make it *look* like a button by setting the `Appearance` property to `Button` in the designer. Here is a simple example where clicking on `mButton` looks at the `Checked` state of `level1` to determine the correct increment value. At the same time, toggling the checked state of `level1` sets the `Increment` value of the `NumericUpDown` control so that the Up/Down arrows *also* use the correct value of 1 or 2.

[image: checkbox looks like a button]

---

*Example of coding the `MainForm` that has the behavior you describe:*

```
public partial class MainForm : Form , INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        level1.Appearance = Appearance.Button;
        numericUpDown.DataBindings.Add(
            nameof(NumericUpDown.Value), 
            this, 
            nameof(Moneycount),
            false,
            DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
    }
    private void mButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Moneycount += level1.Checked ? 2 : 1;
    }
    private void level1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Clicking up/down arrows increments 1 or 2
        numericUpDown.Increment = level1.Checked ? 2 : 1;
    }
    public int Moneycount
    {
        get => _moneyCount;
        set
        {
            if(!Equals(_moneyCount, value))
            {
                _moneyCount = value;
                PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(Moneycount)));
            }
        }
    }
    int _moneyCount = 0;
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

Comment: [Clone](https://github.com/IVSoftware/button-plus-checkbox.git) this sample.

Answer (score 2):

So if I understand you correctly, you want mButton to increment MoneyCount by one every time you press it. But after pressing level1, mButton should increment by 2 instead.

Try this:

```cs
int Moneycount;
int amountToIncrement = 1;
private void mButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Moneycount += amountToIncrement;
    MoneyCount.Text = Moneycount.ToString();
}
private void level1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    amountToIncrement = 2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
Moneycount += 2;
```

this increments by two

Comment: OK, but I think you're missing what aspect of this was causing a problem for the asker.  The "amount to change by" needs to be dynamic based on whether the level1 button was pressed or not.

Comment: Please, read the title of answer. This strict solves the incremental expect, any effects to perform it looks out of context.